# Which to accept; better explanation or better solution

Tags: support

I asked a question on SO and received two answers; one helped me understand the problem, the other provided a way to fix it (though I'm not quite sure if its the preferred solution). Which one should I accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Quoting from the answer there:

> #### Which answer should I choose?
>
> - Don't hesitate to accept an answer that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you.
> - Otherwise, even if there are answers that are *good enough* but that you're not entirely satisfied by, you might wait 24 to 48 hours to
>   give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question
>   with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention
>   as one without an accepted answer.
> - Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is really good practice. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in,
>   uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact a bad hack.
> - **The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.**

Originally formatted there by [Pops ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131713/pops).